# Javascript array when posted(AJAX) is received as single string

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Am trying to post an object that contains an array of strings in javascript to an API c# asp.net but the API receives that array as a single string for some reason instead as an array of strings.
Please note that the only part that the issue occurs is email property
Javascript code:

```
  vm =
    {
        title: $("#formTitle").val(),
        email: function () {
            var arr = [];
            document.getElementById("issueUserList").childNodes.forEach(function(child) {
                arr.push(child.innerText);
            });
            return arr;
        },
        urgencyFlag: parseInt($("#formUrgencyFlag").val()),
        completionFlag: parseInt($("#formCompletionFlag").val()),
        category: {
            id: $("#category").val(),
            description: $("#category :selected").attr("name")
        },
        issueTagsId: $("#tags").val().map(Number),
        description: $("#formDescription").val(),
        solution: $("#formSolution").val(),
        note: $("#formNote").val()
    }
    $.ajax({
            url: "/api/issues",
            method: "POST",
            data: vm
        })
        .done(function() {
            clearIssueForm();
            toastr.success("Issue recorded successfully");
        })
        .fail(function(xhr) {
            if (xhr.status === 404) {
                toastr.error(xhr.responseText
                    .replace("message", "User")
                    .replace("{", "")
                    .replace("}", ""));
            } else {
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
                toastr.error("something unexpected has occured. Please try again");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Now when i debug this one it correctly builds an array of strings.

Api that should receive this code c#

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult CreateIssue(IssueDto dto)
{




    var users = _context.Persons.Where(p => dto.Email.Contains(p.Email)).ToList();
    var issueTags = _context.IssueTagses.Where(
        t => dto.IssueTagsId.Contains(t.Id)).ToList();
    var issue = new Issue
    {
        Title = dto.Title,
        Description = dto.Description,
        Solution = dto.Solution,
        Note = dto.Note,
        UrgencyFlag = dto.UrgencyFlag,
        CompletionFlag = dto.CompletionFlag,
        DateIssueRegistered = DateTime.Now,
        LastUpdate = null,
        CategorieId = dto.Category.Id,
        Persons = users,
        IssueTagses = issueTags
    };
    _context.Issues.Add(issue);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    dto.Id = issue.Id;

    return Created(new Uri(Request.RequestUri +"/" + dto.Id), dto );
}
```

Structure of IssueDto

```
 public class IssueDto
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Solution { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public List<string> Email { get; set; } //Extra 


    public UrgencyFlag UrgencyFlag { get; set; }
    public CompletionFlag CompletionFlag { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateIssueRegistered { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastUpdate { get; set; }

    public IssueCategorieDto Category { get; set; }
    public List<PersonDto> PersonDtos { get; set; }
    public List<IssueTagsDto> IssueTags { get; set; }
    public List<int> IssueTagsId { get; set; } // Extra info
    public int CategorieId { get; set; }
```

Then when posted to the api using jquery $.ajax the api translates this array to a single string as an example "name1,name2" instead of [name1],[name2]therefor my _context.Persons.Where code fails to find anything that matches that in the database as the user does't exist.
Any ideas why that might happen or any additional information you need to understand the issue?

Comment: The code you've shown is just a function that returns an array? Wheres the rest of the code?

Comment: Yes and is received by a View model object that is later passed to the backend via an Ajax call i will fix that to make it more understandable

Comment: Right wheres that code?

Comment: Assuming you are using web api... please post your apicontroller code

Comment: Ok, now it's an object that contains an array...This doesn't really help. Though if you posting that, it's not just an array, it's an object with an email array in it

Comment: show the ajax call code and the controller code, seeing as that's where the problem appears to be. There's a whole chain of events making up this piece of functionality, and you've missed out the most important link.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It seems i failed to make my issue visible, before it even starts executing that code in the api, the email property that it receives so i can search for those emails in my database instead of being treated as [name1], [name2] is threated as "name1.name2" making me write extra code to split it to search my array

Comment: Post your full code for $.ajax method and for server side method

Comment: ok will do give me a sec sorry about this

Comment: Wahts the structure of `IssueDto`? Does it match `vm`?

Comment: Yes it does everything is posted fine untill i wanted to post more than one email thus turned email property to List<string>.Included that as well on original question the error occurs on the email prop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to invoke the function:-

```js
vm = {
  title: $("#formTitle").val(),
  email: function() {
    var arr = [];
    document.getElementById("issueUserList").childNodes.forEach(function(child) {
      arr.push(child.innerText);
    });
    return arr;
  }(), // <--- HERE
  urgencyFlag: parseInt($("#formUrgencyFlag").val()),
  completionFlag: parseInt($("#formCompletionFlag").val()),
  category: {
    id: $("#category").val(),
    description: $("#category :selected").attr("name")
  },
  issueTagsId: $("#tags").val().map(Number),
  description: $("#formDescription").val(),
  solution: $("#formSolution").val(),
  note: $("#formNote").val()
}
```

This will then call the function as soon as the object is created, setting the property to an array.

Comment: Well that was easier than expected, thanks for the help!